# Is there a performance threshold value for Dictionary<K, V>'s count of items?

Tags: .net

I'm creating a embed cache for my project which uses Dictionary as internal storage. Does Dictionary have a performance threshold, like "under count of 10,000,000 KeyValuePair" it's add/get action performs best?

Comment: Why would you need such a huge data in memory? All of this depends on hash-collision, collision is inversely proportional to performance.

Comment: None. IMHO. It will totally depend on hardware, and the types you use. Also, if you need a billion objects in dictionary, you should rather think about a database.

Comment: +1 because it's good to know these types of things, but you also really shouldn't be storing so much in a dictionary that you'd have to, as the above comments have suggested.

Comment: Useful reading: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-size

Comment: Dictionary is very smart about this, it internally re-organizes itself when the hash collision risk gets too large, growing the buckets to the next prime size.  So this is simply not something you have to worry about.  If you *know* that the dictionary is going to be large then set the capacity up front, it helps to avoid the dictionary having to do this.